# Angular.js multiple TextArea

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

repeat in my code

```
<div class="feed-element"ng-repeat="message in messages">
                                <a href="" class="pull-left">
                                    <img alt="image" class="img-circle" src="{{message.src}}"onerror="this.src='https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/transparent-round-icons/512/user.png';">
                                </a>

                                <div class="media-body ">
                                    <small class="pull-right"></small>
                                    <strong> {{message.User}} <br>
                                    <small class="text-muted">{{message.Date}}</small>
                                    <div class="well">
                                       {{message.Question}}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="pull-right">
                                        <div class="well"style="display:{{message.isAnswered}}">{{message.Answer}}</div>
                                        <div class="social-comment"style="display:{{message.isAnswered2}}">

                                            <div class="media-body">
                                                <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Cevap Yazın..."></textarea>
                                            </div>
                                        </div><br>

                                        <a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"style="display:{{message.isAnswered2}};width:150px;"  ng-click="answer(message.Id)"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Mesaj Gönder</a>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

In This code , every message has textarea and a button and every message is unique to any user so when I click one button I want to get text of that's item textarea only, But I couldn't do it how can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Read up on how to use `ng-model`

Answer (score 0):

Replace your textarea as below ,
yourtextareavalue should be your    key name to bind values

```
<textarea class="form-control" ng-model="message.yourTextAreaValue" 
placeholder="Cevap Yazın..."></textarea>
```